# When was Sia born?

Tags: time

John was born on 15 August 2007. If Sia is 17 year older than John. On which day Sia was born?

> Tuesday, Wednesday, Monday, Friday

Comment: Change your user name before some body catch you :-)

Comment: i wonder if this is off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

> Sia was literally 17 years older, that means she was born on August 15, 1990. This is a Wednesday which matches with John's birth date.

Comment: Please tell me how suddenly did you get the answers is there any tricks to solve such problems (date related problems

Comment: I just looked up 2007 August calendars and 1990 August calendars to determine the day of the week :) @DiculSmerd